# Blazor - private component

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor-server-side

Is there way to create a Blazor component private for the project that it is being used in?

For example, let's look at Razor Class Library `ProjectOne` that contains two components: omponent `ComponentA` and component `ComponentB`. The component `ComponentB` is child of component `ComponentA`.

`ProjectOne` structure:

ProjectOne

---- Components

---------- ComponentA.razor

---------- ComponentB.razor

There is another project which is Blazor application `ProjectTwo`. There is a reference in this project to `ProjectOne`. When calling component `ComponentA` in razor page, the child component `ComponentB` is visible and accessable as well.

Is there a way to create this child component `ComponentB` internal only for project `ProjectOne` where it is being used within the component `ComponentA`?

Answer (score 5):

As it looks like the sub-component needs to be public, rather than put it in another project, I just put it in a deeper namespace.

If the root component that I want to expose publicly is in

```
MyApp.Components.Widget
```

then I put the child components in

```
MyApp.Components.Widget.Internal
```

Achieves a similar outcome to the advice from the earlier answer without the need for another project, seeing as the best we can do is obfuscate it in lieu of making it 'internal' or 'private'.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not ideal but create another project to support your public project and only referenced by your public project.  Your consuming project only references your public project. So for you example it would change to ...

- ProjectTwo (App project)

  - ProjectOne (Api component project)

    - ProjectOneInternalUse (supporting project for API use)

(unfortunately you still need to refefence the 'internal use' project in ProjectTwo (the app project) but at least it will be marked as internal in the naming within the namespace)